# Syntax errors when using example code for JQuery Chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I've been using this example code to activate chosen fields

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        '.chosen-select': { "proyects", "users" }, //This is necessary to tell the plugin which select fields will be used in chosen 
        '.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
        '.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
    }

    for (var selector in config) {
        $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
</script>
```

However I get a complaint about a javascript syntax error on the `.chosen-select` line that reads: 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,` (In Chrome) and I get `SyntaxError: missing : after property id` (In IceWeasel)

However I can't figure it out. I can get chosen to work, but I have a lot of trouble doing it. I'm thinking it might be because of this.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Read the error message... `{proyects: 'users'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects have their key/value pairs separated by `:` not `,`. Change this:

```
{ "proyects", "users" }
```

To this:

```
{ "proyects": "users" }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Chosen plugin, but all I can tell you is that the syntax you're using is incorrect. It's possible you need to pass an array, although I can't see any settings in the documentation that accept an array.

Comment: I understand, what you are saying. But the only way I could get chosen to work is by adding the ids between the curly braces. I'll ask another question, regarding what is the correct way to make chosen work

Answer (score 0):

### Correct Your JSON syntax

```
 var config = {
          '.chosen-select' : {'proyects':'users'}, 
    '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
    '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      }
```

Comment: This is the error?? But that makes no sense. As I understand, this should be a list of the ids of the fields that are supposed to use chosen. If I don't LIST (this is NOT a key value pair) those IDs the select field does not transform into a chosen type select....